# Python ser.readline() not reading incoming data from arduino via usb

Tags: python, plot, arduino, serial-port

First time posting here so I apologize if I posted this incorrectly.

So currently I'm trying to make a digital stethoscope and plot the data live via python. I have a stethoscope with a mic shoved inside hooked up to a breadboard with the mic test circuit. This goes into an arduino which then sends the data via usb to my laptop. Currently my python code can display the incoming data live which is awesome. The problem is when I tap on the stethoscope, the incoming data should change. If I'm displaying the serial data via arduino or minicom, the data does change when I hit the stethoscope. But when I look at my python plot the data doesn't change and I can't figure out why. Here is my code;

Arduino

```
int sensorValue = 0;  //value read from the pot

void setup() {
  //init serial communications at 115200 bps;
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  //read A0
  sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

  //Serial.write(sensorValue);

  //Serial.print("The Voltage is: ");
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  //Serial.println("V");
}
```

Python

```
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from drawnow import *

voltArray = []
count = 0
arduinoData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
plt.ion() 

def makeFig():
    plt.title('Stethascope Data')
    plt.plot(voltArray,'bo-')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.ylabel('Voltage (V)')
    plt.ylim(0,5)


while True:

    while (arduinoData.inWaiting()==0): #wait here until there is data
        pass #do nothing

    arduinoString = arduinoData.readline()
    print arduinoString


    try:
        volt = float(arduinoString)

    except ValueError:
#        pass
        print 'ValueError'

    print 'Pin Value: ', volt

    volt = volt*(5.0/1024.0) #arduino reads 0-5V, 10bit resolution
                             #2^10 = 1024, arduino outputs 0-1023

    print 'Voltage: ', volt

    voltArray.append(volt) #append volt value into array

    drawnow(makeFig)

    count = count + 1

    if (count > 50):
        voltArray.pop(0) 

    print 'End Loop'
    print
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you import numpy and then never use it?  Can matplotlib handle Python lists as opposed to numpy arrays?  If the data capture is working correctly the problem has to be in the plotting logic.  What if you put fake data into voltArray (just throw away the real data) and see if it plots correctly?

Comment: So I did some more experimenting and found that the drawnow() function takes about 0.19 seconds to run. If I comment out drawnow() from the code python gets all the data. So now my question is how do I get around drawnow() taking up too much time? 

I import numpy because I plan to use it to calculate my heart rate, I just haven't gotten around to that part of the code yet. Is there a difference between lists vs array in terms of code speed?

Comment: There can be a huge difference in speed - numpy is much faster since it uses C or Fortran arrays of specific type.  In Python lists are generic objects and hence carry a lot of overhead.  The classic solution here is to launch a second thread which unfailingly collects the incoming values into a list, and let the main thread periodically update the plot at some low rate (maybe 2-3 times a second).  In this application maybe you don't need to collect ALL the data, just a representative time slice at a rate that drawnow() can actually handle.